# Can I put a switch in after a GFCI and still have proper protection?

Tags: switch, gfci

I am about to install a fan in the shower stall.  It is code to do so as long as the fan is GFCI protected.  However, I don't want the switch that controls the fan to turn the receptacles on and off.  So, this is the plan:  MAIN CIRCUIT to GFCI to REC #1 to REC #2 to SWITCH to FAN.  I know that everything after the GFCI is protected; but I want to make sure that putting a switch in the chain isn't going to mess anything up in terms of proper GFCI protection for the fan.

Comment: There is no problem with what you want to do.

Comment: The only way that the switch could turn off the receptacles would be if it is in series with them.

Answer (score 1):

A configuration with GFCI protected outlets and switched lights but and unswitched outlets is a completely ordinary and unremarkable configuration.